How can I reliably calculate HVAC capacity needs?
I want to decide on the tonnage of a replacement attic unit. Using various websites I come across numbers in the 3.5 ton to 5 ton range.  None of the four pros who came to home in the last 20 years have mentioned "Manual J" calculations. They go by what is there or the square footage of the home. Currently one company said 3.5 (by square footage), the other 4 (by the existing equipment).
Here is the data:

The house is a 40-year-old structure in the hot and humid southeast Texas (Like Florida).
Area 2200 square foot. One floor.
There are 12 windows and partially glass doors.  200 square foot of double pane windows and 120 square foot of glass doors.
Existing indoor unit (all electric) is a 4 ton unit (20 years old), and the outdoor unit is 3.5 ton (10 years old).
1.5 feet Soffit.
South facing, no tree blockage, but with trees on left and right.
No information as to what insulation I have.

Can a tonnage value be estimated?

Did the old one keep up ?

Upgrade the house insulation and save money on the new unit and on running the new unit for decades after...

@ErikFriesen I felt the rooms at the end of ducts were not cooling or heating properly. On the other hand a pro said you have a 4 inch filter as well as a 1 inch one. So That is why it struggles.

Manual J is a prescriptive method for estimating what the heating or cooling load should be, but it's only as good - or we might cynically say, it's never better than - the data input into it. We can look up in charts and tables the typical insulating value of all kinds of building materials. But are yours assembled and performing the same way those in the tables were? Factors such as workmanship, age, water content, and others will cause performance to deviate from "typical" values. It's also too easy to forget or underestimate infiltration, thermal bridging, internal heat sources, etc.
When there's a system already operating, and especially if you can make some assessment as to whether it performs as per its capacity/rating, that's a fantastic starting point for an estimate. From there you can make adjustments:

does the temperature fall rapidly when the system comes on? -> might be oversized
does the system run for short periods of time? -> might be oversized
does the system turn off for intervals of 20+ minutes even on the hottest of days? -> might be oversized
does the system struggle or outright fail to achieve your desired temperature in the afternoon and evening on the hottest days? (it's ok, and actually means it's sized almost perfectly, if the system runs almost continuously for a few hours straight on those days, but does get the cooling job done.) -> might be undersized


Partial answer.
For a replacement unit, assuming you are not adding or modifying ductwork, the size and number of ducts and returns is a constraint.  If you decide a bigger unit is right but the ductwork doesn't support the required air flow, you won't get better performance and you will get problems.
Conversely, if your old system is too small and struggling and you want a larger unit, adding ducts to the warmest rooms and ensuring appropriate return air paths from those rooms makes a fantastic combination with a bigger A/C.

Add in the insulation values and the quality of sealing of the house.
A 40 year old house will probably be on the low side for insulation and probably poor sealing, unless built to new standards of that time like R-2000. You probably want the higher tonnage estimates, than the lower ones.
Add a bit more if no sun blocking on the windows.
